# Cases of various time symmetries

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, time, time-reversal-symmetry

Is it possible to cook up three physically relevant examples where the Lagrangian has explicit time dependence but the system still has one of the following?

- time-reversal invariance,
- time translation invariance,
- both symmetries unbroken.

**Edits in response to the comments**

Consider an oscillator with an external driving force that is an even function of time, for example, $F(t)=F_0\cos(\omega t)$. We can write an explicitly time-dependent potential $V(x,t)=xF_0\cos(\omega t)$, and therefore, an explicitly time-dependent Lagrangian $L=T-V(x,t)$ in order to produce the correct Eq. of motion. This Lagrangian suggests that the system fails to be time-translation invariant but remains time-reversal invariant. However, such a system is physically ill-defined because, without damping, the response of the system would be infinite at resonance. Once damping is taken into account, the resulting Lagrangian will no longer be time-reversal invariant. Therefore, physical and mathematical consistency requires that this example does violate both time-reversal as well as time-translation symmetries.

- Is there a physical system that violates time-translation but not time-reversal?
- Is there a physical system that violates time-reversal but not time-translation?

Also, I must say that I am not interested in concocted examples that do not have much to do with real life.

Comment: Do you really mean "Is it possible....?" to which the answer is Yes/No, or "Please give me 3 examples...?"

Comment: $L=...+f(t^2)$?

Comment: @sammygerbil Yes. I need three examples. Preferably, 3 physical examples.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform That example is not very physical. Is it?

Comment: It is perfectly physical, by any reasonable definition of "physical". What constraints do you want to impose?

Comment: What real physical system would you associate with it?

Comment: For example an oscillator with an external driving force which is an even function of time.

Comment: @MannyC What would the Lagrangian be for your system?

Comment: The one AccidentalFourierTransform wrote, with the $\ldots$ replaced by any system you like.